# How to trigger resolver in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have problem with resolver that is not called after some changes in useState, I need someway to trigger it manulay for example in useEffect() or tell resolver to be dependent on some state and call every time it changes.

```
const [someData, setSomeData] = useState();
// ...some code like other useState etc

const getValidationSchema = () => yup.lazy((values) => yup.object().shape({ 
// ...some dynamic schema dependent on values and someData
})

const {setValue, formState: {isValid} = useForm({
  mode: 'onChange',
  resolver: yupResolver(getValidationSchema()),
  defaultValues,
})

// ...some code like setValue etc
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `trigger()` method available for that:

```js
const [someData, setSomeData] = useState();
// ...some code like other useState etc

const getValidationSchema = () => yup.lazy((values) => yup.object().shape({ 
// ...some dynamic schema dependent on values and someData
})

const {setValue, trigger, formState: {isValid}} = useForm({
  mode: 'onChange',
  resolver: yupResolver(getValidationSchema()),
  defaultValues,
})

useEffect(() => {
   trigger();
}, [trigger, someData]);
```

You can call it as `trigger()` for the whole form or `trigger("inputName")` or `trigger(["firstName", "lastName"])` for specific inputs.

Source: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/trigger